# Do I have to use an assembler with GNU Lightning?

Tags: assembly, jit

I've recently been interested in GNU Lightning but I was wondering if I have to use an assembler with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. GNU lightning generate (poor, i.e. unoptimized) machine code in memory on the fly without using any external program (such as an assembler).

You should have read the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/manual/html_node/index.html) of GNU lightning before asking and look into the [examples](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/manual/html_node/GNU-lightning-examples.html) there.

Notice that [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) also generates possibly optimized machine code (reusing most of GCC internal middle end and back end passes) but (in some cases, and some releases at least) do require external resources such as the assembler. However, if you have correctly installed [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) you won't see them.